# Selenium Webdriver with Python - NoSuchWindowException after using frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it()

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, iframe, webdriverwait

I'm trying to work with Selenium Webdriver with Python, automating the Chrome browser.

In re-optimising my code, I'm trying to get rid of any `time.sleep()` commands and using implicit and explicit waits when possible.

The part I'm stuck on is an iframe / modal dialog - after switching to it I still need to wait for the modal dialog to load before I can interact with elements without errors.

**Code that works:**

```py
driver.find_element(By.ID, "process").click()   # Process form button - creates modal dialog
time.sleep(2)                                   # Delay to wait for the frame to load
driver.switch_to.frame("acsframe")              # acsframe is the ID of the modal dialog
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, r'input.btn.btn-warning').click() # Cancel button
```

**Code that I'm trying to get to work:**

```py
driver.find_element(By.ID, "process").click() # Process form button
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, "acsframe")))
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, r'input.btn.btn-warning')))
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, r'input.btn.btn-warning').click() # Cancel button
```

**Error Message:**

```
NoSuchWindowException                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-acf8921ff08a> in <module>
      2 WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, "acsframe")))
----> 3 WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, r'input.btn.btn-warning')))
      4 driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, r'input.btn.btn-warning').click()
```

I don't understand how/why I would be getting an error message here. I switch to the frame on line 2, and line 3 works about 1 time in 10, but otherwise throws an error. I know the element locator is right because it worked in the first example. If `time.sleep()` worked, why wouldn't this work?

I've tried changing between XPATH and CSS Selector for locating the elements and it's the same result. There aren't any IDs for the buttons.

**Update: This code also works:**

```
driver.find_element(By.ID, "process").click() # Process form button
time.sleep(2)
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, "acsframe")))
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, r'input.btn.btn-warning')))
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, r'input.btn.btn-warning').click()
```

So it seems that a delay before waiting for the frame fixes it - but isn't that the entire purpose of the command to wait for the frame to be available? I still want a way to get this to work without `time.sleep()`.

[Screenshot of the relevant HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OzRZ.png)

Answer (score 1):

As the element is within an `<iframe>` so you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52603847/how-to-sleep-webdriver-in-python-for-milliseconds/52607451#52607451) for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.ID, "process").click() # Process form button
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, "acsframe")))
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, r'input.btn.btn-warning'))).click()
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)
- [Switch to an iframe through Selenium and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python/44847390#44847390)
- [selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to click Next button with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315587/selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-una/50315715#50315715)
- [selenium in python : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441658/selenium-in-python-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-unable-to/53442511#53442511)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Isn't this functionally the same as what I have done? It throws the same NoSuchWindowException - seems to fail to find the iframe. It works with a time.sleep(2) before the first WebDriverWait.

Comment: @Adam There are delta differences between your code and the code I have offered. However it's true we can't test out code since you haven't provided the relevant HTML.

Comment: I've added a screenshot of some of the relevant HTML - perhaps from that it's clear why it only works with the time.sleep? The iframe takes over a second to load in the webpage.